# OCR for extracting text from cedula/passport C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image-processing, ocr

I'm looking for a `Tesseract` or Google's `Vision API` type of `OCR` which can help in extracting textual information in passport / ID card image, *(which may be captured from mobile or may be scanned. Hence frame size may vary a little)*. I have been through several posts, and and found [Tesseract](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract) as preferred solution.

I also tested my test data using [Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/), and got *99%* accurate and satisfactory results. But I have following problems/requirements:

**Problems**:

- Tesseract is the suggested solution that i found on most of the posts i had been through, but it gives very bad results, as frame may vary. I can't train data, and I'm okay with any **paid** library available to help me in my scenario.
- Vision API gives accurate result, but my requirement is to **not** to use cloud based solution.
- There are few providers, *(eg, [LeadTool](https://www.leadtools.com/), [IdScan](http://idscan.net/) etc.)* which provide this feature, but they use their scanners first to scan the passport. Hence their SDK works for their scanners device.

*Summary*: Is there any available *(paid or opensource)* `c#` library available, which takes passport/cedula image as input, and returns accurate text?. Any suggestion/help will be appreciated.

Comment: There is a propietary solution, but I'm not allowed to share it's name, because it counts for spam here.
However, I suppose I can say if your image is recognized by this library or not, if you attach the image to your question.

Comment: @НадеждаТарашкевич Thank you. Following is the link to sample image. Assume there is extra space as well.
http://images.telemetro.com/nacionales/Registro-Civil-Cedulacion-atenderan-Ancon_MEDIMA20140214_0134_23.jpg

Answer (score 4):

Company called MicroBlink created BlinkID SDK to scan passports, ID cards. It is not free for commercial usage, but free for development. Link to SDK's site [HERE](https://microblink.com/blinkid). Tesseract OCR tool may give you false results because you probably have not done any processing for an image before OCR scan, which is mandatory if you want a proper result, especially for images of passports and ID's and so on. For image processing you can use OpenCV (free), but it may take you time to learn computer vision and image processing (which are very rewarding actually).

Comment: I doubt *BlinkID* is for ios/android platform, but not for .NET (C#). Can you guide me on this?

Comment: It is only offering SDKs for ios and Android.

Comment: BlinkID is available for other platforms as well

Answer (score 3):

I'm one of the developers in [MicroBlink](https://microblink.com), which is a company specializing in development of barcode and OCR solutions.

Tesseract is indeed one of the options you have. The problem with Tesseract is that it's hard to set the right parameters to get really accurate OCR results. And you still need to implement the data extraction logic on top of the OCR results. And integration on iOS/Android requires two separate codebases.

Google Cloud Vision gives very accurate OCR result, but as you said, it performs image processing on server side, which raises privacy and security concerns regarding sending private ID information over the network to third parties.

There are other companies developing similar products with similar properties (server side, no data extraction, etc..)

MicroBlink's [BlinkID](https://microblink.com/blinkid) is different in the sense that it performs all processing locally (without server side connection). It uses our proprietary machine-learning based OCR engine to ensure data is captured correctly. It supports MRZ, PDF417 barcodes, and scanning the front side of some ID documents (such as UK Driver's licenses, Malaysian IDs, EU IDs...). All ID data is parsed and verified according to country's standards with checksum validation.

BlinkID is provided as a native iOS, Android and Windows Phone 8 SDKs, Phonegap / Cordova plugins for iOS and Android, and Xamarin component (C#) for iOS and Android.

There are also server side library (available on request) which can run on Linux / Windows / MacOS and which has C API and that can be used from .NET application using C++/CLI. Our development team is here to help with the integration in a .NET app.

Please contact support@microblink.com for more information on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

[Asprise C# .NET OCR and Barcode Recognition SDK](http://asprise.com/royalty-free-library/c%23-sharp.net-ocr-api-overview.html) can recognize both normal text, MRZ data and barcodes on passports and other identity documents. The accuracy rate for MRZ data is extremely high.

You can simply pass input images in formats like BMP, JPG, PNG, PDF or TIFF.

Many government agencies use [Asprise OCR to read passport MRZ](http://asprise.com/ocr-document-scanning-java.net/library-api-about.html) information.

You may contact [Asprise support](http://asprise.com/ocr-document-scanning-java.net/library-api-contact.html) to obtain a special evaluation version for your scenario.

Comment: Budget Friendly, Royalty-Free article states that "Royalty-free means you pay when you order a development license..." I thought blue means blue ;)

Comment: "Royalty-Free" means you don't need to pay when you distribute or deploy. Please feel free to download our free trial and test out the quality of our code workmanship.

Answer (score 1):

Just a correction about LEADTOOLS needing to...

> "use their scanners first to scan the passport. Hence their SDK
>   works for their scanners device"

This part is not correct. We do not make or sell any type of scanning device. LEADTOOLS SDKs can use different standard devices (Twain and WIA on Windows, Sane on Linux, and cameras on Android and iOS devices using the operating system's own APIs). The OCR and ID recognition is then done through software.